# Comparision between "cts.values" and "cts.elementValues"

Tags: xquery, marklogic, marklogic-9, marklogic-dhf, multi-model-database

I can see that [`cts.values`](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts.values) and [`cts.elementValues`](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts.elementValues) has similar use.

In that case,  what is the difference between both of them in terms of performance? Which is more efficient?

Answer (score 4):

They should perform the same. Both of those functions provide a way to query lexicons (range indexes).

With `cts.values()`, the first parameter is a `cts.reference[]`. So, that means that you can provide any of the `cts.reference` types: [`cts.elementReference`](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts.elementReference), [`cts.elementAttributeReference`](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts.elementAttributeReference), [`cts.fieldReference`](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts.fieldReference), [`cts.jsonPropertyReference`](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts.jsonPropertyReference), [`cts.pathReference`](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts.pathReference), as well as [`cts.collectionReference`](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts.collectionReference) and [`cts.uriReference`](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts.uriReference).

With the `cts.elementValues()` query, the first parameter is an `xs.QName[]` for the element(s), rather than a `cts.reference[]`.

These other lexicon values functions have a similar difference in the parameters, but are also effectively a different way of invoking `cts.values()`:

- https://docs.marklogic.com/cts.fieldValues
- https://docs.marklogic.com/cts.elementAttributeValues
- https://docs.marklogic.com/cts.uris
- https://docs.marklogic.com/cts.collections

Comment: Minor addition: the more specific `cts.elementValues` e.a are the original function names. Over time more and more index types were added, and at some point it made sense to provide a more generic `cts.values` that takes references instead. Similar story for `cts.elementRangeQuery` vs `cts.rangeQuery`. Around the same time `cts.valueTuples` was added as well if I am not mistaken, that allows a random combination of references to be passed in, as opposed to the much more rigid `cts.elementValueCoOccurrences` e.a..